# Cross product and projection

Tags: cross-product, projection

$\textbf{Problem:}$ Let $v_1,...,v_{n-2} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\{v_1,...,v_{n-2}\}$ is linearly independent. Let $B = (v_1,...,v_{n-2})$ and $C = \text{Col}(B)$. If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, show that $$\text{Proj}_{C^\perp}(x) = \frac{-1}{\det(B^TB)}X(v_1,...,v_{n-2},X(v_1,...,v_{n-2},x))$$ where $X$ represents the cross product.

The definition of cross product that I was given is $X: M_{n \times (n-1)}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that if $A = (u_1,...,u_{n-1}) \in M_{n \times (n-1)}(\mathbb{R}) $ where each $u_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $X(A)_j = (-1)^{n+j} \det(A^{(j)})$ where $A^{(j)}$ is obtained from A by removing the $j^{th}$ row.

I'm not quite sure how to proceed with this problem. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: So...$\;B\;$ is a matrix, right? And I am guessing $\;U\;$ is some subspace of $\;\Bbb R^n\;$ ...? Then...what is on the right of $\;\cfrac{-1}{\det(B^TB)}\;$ ...? What is  that $\; \;X\;$ ? Finally, and as far as I am aware, cross product is only defined on $\;\Bbb R^3\;$ ...Did you mean to write there the determinant of something instead?

Comment: I have updated the definition that I was given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ lies in the span of $v_1,\cdots,v_{n-2}$ then both sides of the equation are  $0$ and we are done.  Otherwise let $e_1,\cdots,e_{n-2}$ be an orthonormal basis for $C$ and let $e_{n-1}$ be ${\rm Proj}_{C^\perp}(x)$ normalised. Finally let $e_n$ extend this to an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with positive orientation.

If we define our operations in terms of this basis, then the result is clear.  It remains to show that the right hand side of the equation is invariant under choice of orthonormal, positively oriented basis.

Let $A\in SO(n)$.  Clearly $(AB)^T(AB)=B^T(A^TA)B=B^TB$.

For any $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have:
\begin{equation}
X(Aa_1,\cdots, Aa_{n-1})\cdot Ab\\=|Aa_1\cdots Aa_{n-1}\,Ab|\\=|A||a_1\cdots a_{n-1}\, b|\\= |a_1\cdots a_{n-1}\, b|\\=X(a_1,\cdots,a_{n-1})\cdot b\\=AX(a_1,\cdots,a_{n-1})\cdot Ab
\end{equation}

As $b$ was arbitrary and $A$ surjective, we have $AX(a_1,\cdots,a_{n-1})=X(Aa_1,\cdots, Aa_{n-1})$.

Thus the desired equation holds, independent of the choice of orthonormal, positively oriented basis.

Comment: What does $a_i$ represent in this case and is there a simpler explanation as I don't know much about SO(n) as well as its properties. How does showing $AX(a_1,...,a_{n-1}) = X(Aa_1,...,Aa_{n-1})$ relate back to the question? Thanks.

Comment: The $a_i$ represent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  A matrix $A$ is in $SO(n)$ if it transforms the standard basis to an orthonormal basis with positive orientation.  Equivalently $A^TA=I_n$ and $|A|=1$.  Are you happy with the first part:  if you fix vectors $v_1,\cdots,v_n,x$ and define $X$ and the matrix $B$ in terms of the basis $e_1,\cdots,e_n$ then the result is clear?  Everything else is just showing that the basis does not matter.

Comment: The point is that the vectors $v_i$ and $x$ only become $n$-tuples of numbers once you define a basis.  Thus to obtain the matrix $B$ and the operation $X$, the way you have defined it, you need to pick a basis.  In your question the basis is the standard one.  However the question becomes easier if you use the $e_i$ instead.  Then you just need to show that the right hand side of the  equation is the same either way.  The left hand side does not change because it is just projection, which does not need a basis to be defined.

Comment: Thanks, I think I finally get what the solution meant now. Sorry for my lack of knowledge. One final clarification that I would like to ask is that can you demonstrate the part “if we define our operations in this basis then the result is clear”? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What I am saying is that you should first answer the question in the simple case where each vector $v_i$ has $0$'s in its last $2$ co-ordinates, and $x$ has a $0$ in its final co-ordinate.  Using the definition of $X$ that you gave first work out $u=X(v_1,\cdots,v_{n-2},x)$.  Then input that into  $X(v_1,\cdots,v_{n-2},u)$.  Then evaluate ${\rm Proj}_{C^\perp}x$ and Det$(B^TB)$.  You should get the same thing on both sides.  If you get stuck with this let me know how far you got.  Once you have done this, the rest of my answer was reducing the general case, to this simple case.